# Removing the first element from a list inside a loop

Tags: python, arraylist

I am creating a function to keep removing the first element of a list if its an even number
this is what i tried, but the outcome of the second print statement is still giving me a list with 10 inside it

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
    for num in lst:
      if lst[0] % 2 == 0:
        lst.pop(0)
    return lst


print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]))
[11, 12, 15]

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
[10]

expected/desired outcome:
[11, 12, 15]
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing elements from the list you are iterating could have side effects.
Iterate over a shallow copy of the original list and remove terms, *in-place*, from the original one.

Here an example with shallow copy (either use `[:]` or call the `copy()` method)

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
    for num in lst[:]:
      if lst[0] % 2 == 0:
        lst.pop(0)
    return lst
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of stating this problem is to say that any even number before the first odd number should be removed.
This means you only need to iterate through the list until you find the first odd number as the rest of the list remains unchanged.

This means the loop can exit early if an odd number is found returning a slice of the list at the point the odd number was found.

This avoids the bad practice of modifying the list that is currently being iterated over.

For example:

```py
>>> def delete_starting_evens(lst):
...     for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
...         if num % 2:  # if odd number found
...             return lst[idx:]
...     return []  # No odd numbers found in list, return empty list
>>> print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]))
[11, 12, 15]
>>> print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
[]
```